# Is it possible to use SurveyMonkeyAPI to modify an existing SurveyMonkey survey?

Tags: surveymonkey

the list of SurveyMonkey API Methods does not appear to include a method to modify an existing survey.   Is this right?   Are there any development plans to include such a method?  For a project, we want to be able to modify a presentation type question and add custom questions to a standard survey.

thanks

Comment: just wanna add that this has been updated and you can do that now.

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  For now there is no way to modify an existing survey, just create new ones.

Regarding upcoming API features, it is unlikely SurveyMonkey would comment publicly on these, but if you are potentially a large API partner you could reach out and ask about this functionality via api-support@surveymonkey.com.